# System-config.ts with angular cli

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am working with angular2 for frontend dev and have installed a new project using angular-cli. I want to use ng2-bootstrap, for this some config needs to be done in system-config.ts file. However, I can not see this file being installed as default by angular-cli. I am following this link for the setup https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/. The missing file raises a doubt, if this is the correct way to implement third party packages with latest release. I am using angular version 2.3.1. Please suggest the right way to add ng2-bootstrap in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

there is no system.js in your project. angular-cli uses webpack as a file bundler. 
follow this setup it's easy :

[ngBootsrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md)